# Regular expression extract specific part

Tags: python, regex

I have a string `'(test)skip(test774)2;3(xx2324)'`. The presence of the word `'skip'` is necessary.

```
re.search('skip[(].+[)]', args[0]).group(0)
```

gives me `'skip(test774)'`, but not `'test774'`. I can could use slicing `[5:-1]` to get `'test774'`, but it's too clumsy

What the easiest way to get only the value in brackets ('test774') using regular expressions?

Comment: Have you considered adding a capturing group around the part you actually want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To isolate the text you want, use a capturing group around the part of the regex that matches that text.

```
re.search('skip[(]([^)]+)[)]', args[0]).group(1)
```

The change I made is where you have `.+` (any non-empty sequence of characters), I have `([^)]+)` (a capturing group containing a non-empty sequence of characters other than `)`; this means this part of the match stops just before the first `)`, rather than just before the last `)`, as `.+` would).

[regex101.com demo and explanation](https://regex101.com/r/o6JKAR/2)

Comment: This [fails](https://regex101.com/r/wwSYoT/1) the example input. You need to either make the evaluation within the capture group _lazy_ `(.+?)` or, for better performance, just negate a closing parenthesis `([^)]+)`.

Comment: I'd recommend as well dropping a link to debuggex/regex101 and explaining why this works compared to what he had. That way someone who has a similar problem may get a better idea of how to solve their issue. Code-only answers are generally considered low quality.